# Node.js/Express redirect all to angular 2 page

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am creating an Angular 2 app with Node.js and Express.
The problem I am having is that my routes file doesnt work with a wildcard. Everytime I visit the page with anything other then `/` (for example `/test`) it says the following: `ReferenceError: path is not defined`
My server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const routes = require('./routes');
const data = require('./articles.json');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('App started on port 8080');
});
```

My /routes/index.js:

```
const routes = require('express').Router();

routes.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = routes;
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to require the path package in your index.js too

**/routes/index.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const routes = require('express').Router();

routes.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Oh my god thanks. I moved everything to a routes file but forget the path. Lol

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: I'll accept it in 8 minutes (SO Timer won't let me accept it so soon).

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen sure, no rush :-)