# How to tell express to serve a particular angular "page"

Tags: angular, express, routes, mean-stack

I have written an Angular app and an Express app. Then I compiled the Angular app and copy pasted `index.html` and other `js/CSS` files in Express's `views` and `public` folders respectively.

Now, when I go to root (`localhost:3000` in my case), it works fine. If I click on any link (say sign up `RouterLink`) on the page, which will trigger any angular router, it works fine and open that particular page(Sign up page). Now if I reload it again it will produce `Cannot GET /signup`. This may happen since there is no `signup` page in `views` folder. So my question is:

1. How can I make my MEAN app serve Angular pages in accordance with Angular routes?
2. How can I use express route to control Angular route?

Comment: I don't know if I properly understood your question, but I think you should redirect all your Express routes to your `index.html` so that Angular will take care of routing. Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870014/2702370

Comment: I am not sure "copy pasted index.html and other js/CSS files " is the right way to deply an Angular app after compiling. After 'ng build --prod' your compiled app, all of it, is in the "dist" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the hash strategy for fix this bug

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: true
});
```

alternatively use this in your app.js in express application

```
app.get('**', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
    // Skip API calls
        res.status(200).sendFile(pathJoin(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Can you explain how useHash works?

Comment: As of https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule : useHash enables the location strategy that uses the URL fragment instead of the history API.
Means your url is not *blabla.com/#/home* but *blabla.com/home* then, which works perfectly with the express snippet.