# Trying to use Angular as my router but I get a NodeJS Server 'Cannot GET /[something]' error

Tags: node.js, express, angular7

I am using NodeJS / ExpressJS as my server but I want to use Angular 7 as my router. I have my Angular routing script in place and that appears to be working because when I set the login component to load Path '' it loads the component at example.com and if I change the router path from '' to 'login' the login component no longer loads at example.com

However, my server.js script throws a "Cannot GET /" error when I add anything after .com/.

I set my Angular router to load a login component when the url is example.com/login however my error is "Cannot GET /login".

I believe my express server script is using /login and adding that to my directory destination like dist/ngtb/login when I need to always route to dist/ngtb no matter what the path is example.com/what_Ever_This_Path_Is so that my Angular application is read and initialized and it can do the routing.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const apps = express();

const port = process.hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback.PORT || 80;
const ports = process.hasUncaughtExceptionCaptureCallback.PORT || 443;

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('private_key.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl.cer', 'utf8');

var credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
};

apps.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/ngtb'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url));
apps.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/ngtb')));

const serverhttp = http.createServer(app);
const serverhttps = https.createServer(credentials, apps);

serverhttp.listen(port);
serverhttps.listen(ports);
```

Comment: Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870014/5369031

Comment: The only difference between that persons code and my code really is they are requiring a JSON file and routing and using router.get vs my apps.get. However, I don’t understand what their JSON file is they are requiring to variable data and I don’t know what that does because they don’t even use variable data. So I don’t understand what my code is missing and why their code works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understand your problem but try to refer to the index.html in your dist folder.

Comment: That causes my index.html file to load but now somehow always prevents the entire Angular application from loading as well. Only the blank template html files loads but the Cannot Get error is gone. Before the application worked so long as the url was example.com/ doing example.com/login resulted in Cannot Get error. Now example.com/[anything here] loads the index.html file but the application is not initialized and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

The path used in the .use and .get lines should be “dist/ngtb/“ not “dist/ngtb” the missing slash caused the Cannot Get error when anything was added to the url path. Now Angular routing is up work working perfect.